# Best way to parse JSON boolean?

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, boolean

What is the right way of parsing a boolean in Objective-C

Currently I do it like this:

```
bool success = [(NSNumber*)[result objectForKey:@"success"]integerValue] == 1;

if(success){
  NSLog(@"successful");                  
}
```

I mean this works, but it doesnt seem right I couldnt find another way.

Comment: Well, there is `boolValue` (instead of `integerValue`), but it's pretty analogous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
bool success = [(NSNumber*)[result objectForKey:@"success"]integerValue] == 1;
```

You could just do instead:

```
bool success = [result[@"success"] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing slightly better comes to mind and it is [boolValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/boolValue).

```
BOOL success = [(NSNumber*)[result objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Actually, this should simply be `BOOL success = [result[@"success"] boolValue];`.